# How we can upload more than one image for category in shopify?

Tags: shopify, shopify-template

I want to show the menu like when i am on a category then i can show more than one image of category.In admin it only provide to upload one image so what is best way to do to show more than one image for a category.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

There is no best way. There are as many creative ways as you can think of though to just get the job done. One example is to use **Assets**. With a file naming scheme such as the handle of your collection, you could load alternate images with some scheme like:

```
{{ 'collection-handle1' | asset_url }}     
{{ 'collection-handle2' | asset_url }}
{{ 'collection-handle3' | asset_url }}
```

Till you are happy. Or you could save all your collection (*category*) images in a Metafield resource, and thus render them from that.

There are two solutions for you. *Best* is a loaded term. You're on your own there.

Comment: {{ 'collection-handle1' | asset_url }}  in this collection-handle1 is just a string or tile of image?

Comment: name of your file. a string.

Answer (score 1):

You can use collection metafields to add images URL :

- Install this [chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/shopifyfd-dashboard-tool/lffljkleilfpjlmcdnoaghhcbnemelge)
- Host your images in your store (settings => files)
- Get the URL of image and store in a collection metafields (chose a namespace and a key)
- You can then access the URL in liquid in the collection object `{{ collection.metafields.NAMESPACE.KEY }}`

Comment: How we can create collection meta field can you suggest me the steps i am new comer on shopify.thanks.

Comment: You can install it with the chrome extension that I linked in my answer

Comment: ok i tried with this when i am going to click on icon then it shows shopify FD loaded but it is not showing any where do you know where i can the UI of this extension?

Comment: sometimes the extension is not working, so refresh the browser and click again. The UI is in the right column

Comment: I tried but show only an arrow that says to click to Toggle when i am clicking on this nothing happened can you tell it may be the issue that i am working on trial version not purchased yet ?